# Option to arrange answers according to vote

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, voting

It's really frustrating to have -1 and -3 voted answers sit on top of a +99 voted answer. ([this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15/)).
Please provide individual users the option to automatically arrange answers according to number of votes.

Comment: This will surely not be addressed on a site-by-site basis as it is a basic feature of the engine. Further, it *has* been brought up there before. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161946/rethinking-sort-order-of-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111230/shouldnt-the-answer-with-more-votes-be-above-the-accepted-answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2929/2451

Comment: Darn, now I really want Lumo to get an additional upvote for his answer there ... :-D !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I agree that the top up-voted answers should be positioned before the answers with less up-votes.

Comment: I discovered that simply logging out makes the answers get positioned the way I want it. It might be a glitch, but I love it!